# Perl: Final Output Line in Foreach Loop Prints Twice

Tags: perl, output, repeat

I'm trying to write a very simple script that takes two words from STDIN and outputs TRUE if they're anagrams and FALSE if not. My main issue is that if the two words aren't anagrams (this is the final "else" statement in the script), the output looks like:

Sorry, that's not an anagram pair
Sorry, that's not an anagram pair

where I just want:

Sorry, that's not an anagram pair

Other, more minor issues for the especially generous:

- I know what the FALSE values are for Perl, but I can't get the script to print FALSE by, for example, setting a variable to '' or 0, etc. or saying "return ''". Ideally, I wouldn't have to put "print TRUE/FALSE" in the script at all.
- I put in the last elsif statement in the script to see if it would affect the printing twice problem. It didn't, and now I'm curious why my m// expression doesn't work. It's supposed to find pairs that are identical except that one has more whitespace than the other.

Here's the script! I'm sorry it's so long - again, the problem is at the very end with the final "else" statement. Many thanks!!!

```
#To Run: Type start.pl on the command line.
#The script should prompt you to enter a word or phrase.
#Once you've done that, it'll prompt you for another one.
#Then you will be told if the two terms are anagrams or not.

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

#I have to use this to make STDIN work. IDK why.

$|=1;

#variables

my $aWord;
my $bWord;
my $word;
my $sortWord;
my $sortWords;
my @words;
my %anaHash;

print "\nReady to play the anagram game? Excellent.\n\nType your first word or phrase, then hit Enter.\n\n";

$aWord = <STDIN>;
chomp $aWord;

print "\n\nThanks! Now type your second word or phrase and hit Enter.\n\n";

$bWord = <STDIN>;
chomp $bWord;

#This foreach loop performs the following tasks:

#1. Pushes the two words from STDIN into an array (unsure if this is really necessary)
#2. lowercases everything and removes all characters except for letters & spaces
#3. splits both words into characters, sorts them alphabetically, then joins the sorted letters into a single "word"
#4.pushes the array into a hash

@words = ($bWord, $aWord);
foreach $word (@words) {
    $word =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
    $word =~ s/[^a-z ]//ig;
    $sortWord = join '', sort(split(//, $word));
    push @{$anaHash{$sortWord}}, $word;
}

#This foreach loop tries to determine if the word pairs are anagrams or not.

foreach  $sortWords (values %anaHash) {

    #"if you see the same word twice AND the input was two identical words:"

    if (1 < @$sortWords  &&
    @$sortWords[0] eq @$sortWords[1]) {
    print "\n\nFALSE: Your phrases are identical!\n\n";
    }

    #"if you see the same word twice AND the input was two different words (i.e. a real anagram):"

    elsif (1 < @$sortWords &&
       @$sortWords[0] ne @$sortWords[1]) {
    print "\n\nTRUE: @$sortWords[0] and @$sortWords[1] are anagrams!\n\n";
    }

    #this is a failed attempt to identify pairs that are identical except one has extra spaces. Right now, this fails and falls into the "else" category below.

    elsif  (@$sortWords[0] =~ m/ +@$sortWords[-1]/ ||
        @$sortWords[-1] =~ m/ +@$sortWords[0]/) { 
    print "\n\FALSE: @$sortWords[0] and @$sortWords[-1] are NOT anagrams. Spaces are characters, too!\n\n";
    }

    #This is supposed to identify anything that's not an acronym. But the output prints twice! It's maddening!!!!
    else {
    print "Sorry, that's not an anagram pair\n";    
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times does that last foreach loop run?

Comment: When you supply _different_ words your hash will have two keys (one for each `$sortWord`) and each key will have only one value in its arrayref. So both `if` and the first `elsif` are false; in the last `elsif` you end up matching that one word to itself but with spaces -- it fails.  So you wind up in the `else`, for both words.

Comment: There is no "FALSE" or such value in Perl; if you want that you print it. (There are `0` and empty string `''`  and `undef`. If you attempt to print a variable which is `undef` you'll get a warning.)  I don't see how a script would know what to print.

Comment: @zdim, thanks so much, that's exactly what I figured was happening. Any suggestions on how to get it to NOT happen? Like saying "else { only look at one of the variables; print "blah blah"; }

Comment: Oh, right: If the words are same or anagrams your hash will have one key, if they aren't it will have more than one key -- in which case you don't need this analysis.  So check that first.

Comment: @zdim, also, thanks so much for your comment on TRUE/FALSE ... I've been trying to make the script return those values all day, with utter failure.

Comment: @zdim, so sorry, what do you mean by "this analysis"? If the user inputs two phrases that are anagrams, they need to be told "TRUE, these are anagrams" or whatever. This part of the script works fine, for the reasons you've already pointed out. Thanks!!!

Comment: I mean, if the words are different and not anagrams your hash gets two keys, otherwise one.  So you first check whether the hash has more than one key and if it does you inform them that the words are not anagrams and exit.  Otherwise, the program proceeds to the "analysis" (I meant the loop over hash values).

Comment: Did that make sense?  So, `if (keys %anaHash > 1) { say "Not anagrams"; exit };`  Then follows the code that iterates over hash values.

Comment: The `say` is print with added newline.  You need `use feature qw(say)` at the beginning to enable it (not if you have `use v5.XX` larger than 5.10, or you use some modules that enable it).

Comment: @zim, awesome, awesome, thank you. I'm so excited. I'll let you know the results!!!!!

Comment: @zdim, thank you so much again. In the interest of helping the community, here is the re-written end of the script sans comments to stay within the character limits:

if (keys %anaHash > 1) {
    say "\n\nFALSE: Your two terms are not acronyms.";
    exit;
} 

foreach  $sortWords (values %anaHash) { 
    if (1 < @$sortWords  &&
 @$sortWords[0] eq @$sortWords[1]) {
 say "\n\nFALSE: Your phrases are identical!\n";
    }

    elsif (1 < @$sortWords &&
    @$sortWords[1] ne @$sortWords[0]) {
 say "\n\nTRUE: @$sortWords[0] and @$sortWords[1] are anagrams!";
    }
}

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1225564).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's useful to print out the contents of `%anaHash` after you've finished building it, but before you start examining it. Using the words "foo" and "bar", I get this result using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

```
$VAR1 = {
          'abr' => [
                     'bar'
                   ],
          'foo' => [
                     'foo'
                   ]
        };
```

So the hash has two keys. And as you loop round all of the keys in the hash, you'll get the message twice (once for each key).

I'm not really sure what the hash is for here. I don't think it's necessary. I think that you need to:

1. Read in the two words
2. Convert the words to a canonical format
3. Check if the two strings are the same

Simplified, your code would look like this:

```
print 'Give me a word: ';
chomp(my $word1 = <STDIN>);
print 'Give me another word: ';
chomp(my $word2 = <STDIN>);

# convert to lower case
$word1 = lc $word1;
$word2 = lc $word2;

# remove non-letters
$word1 =~ s/[^a-z]//g;
$word2 =~ s/[^a-z]//g;

# sort letters
$word1 = join '', sort split //, $word1;
$word2 = join '', sort split //, $word2;

if ($word1 eq $word2) {
  # you have an anagram
} else {
  # you don't
}
```

Comment: thank you so much; I think you're right. I do feel that "yes" and "yes" shouldn't be anagrams, but maybe I can check after the clean-up and before the split/join. I'll let you know how it went in the morning!

Comment: @Rebecca: Good point. I suggest checking for identical strings after converting to lower case.

Comment: Dave, also, this will make "to, by" match "Toby" which I don't think is fair, either. :) Still though, I think you're correct.

Comment: Sorry, babbling. All I need to do is add spaces after the [a-z]'s.

Answer (score 0):

My final answer, thanks so much to Dave and @zdim! I'm so happy I could die.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

#I have to use this to make STDIN work. IDK why.

$|=1;

#declare variables below

print "First word?\n";

$aWord = <STDIN>;
chomp $aWord;

print "Second word?\n";

$bWord = <STDIN>;
chomp $bWord;

#clean up input
$aWord =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
$bWord =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
$aWord =~  s/[^a-z ]//ig;
$bWord =~  s/[^a-z ]//ig;

#if the two inputs are identical, print FALSE and exit
if ($aWord eq $bWord) {
    say "\n\nFALSE: Your phrases are identical!\n";
    exit;
}

#split each word by character, sort characters alphabetically, join characters

$aSortWord = join '', sort(split(//, $aWord));
$bSortWord = join '', sort(split(//, $bWord));

#if the sorted characters match, you have an anagram
#if not, you don't

if ($aSortWord eq $bSortWord) {
  say "\n\nTRUE: Your two terms are anagrams!";
}
else {
    say "\n\nFALSE: Your two terms are not acronyms.";
}
```

Comment: `$aWord =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/` is a rather over-complicated way to write `lc $aWord` :-)

Comment: I know. It's just a habit. :)

Comment: I usually have long lists of s// and m// and I like seeing them all together. If that makes sense.